# Multiple query don't get executed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiple query that doesn't work. When I press submit on the former page, I get to a blank page and nothing is being inserted in the table "answer_det" in my database and the text "Information stored successfully" doesn't appear. What do I do wrong?

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

$pid5 = $_POST['pid4'];
    
$aid1 = $_POST['a1'];
$aid2 = $_POST['a2'];
$aid3 = $_POST['a3'];
$aid4 = $_POST['a4'];    
    
$answ1 = $_POST['ans1'];
$answ2 = $_POST['ans2'];
$answ3 = $_POST['ans3'];
$answ4 = $_POST['ans4'];
    
$point1 = $_POST['pointset1'];  
$point2 = $_POST['pointset2'];  
$point3 = $_POST['pointset3'];  
$point4 = $_POST['pointset4'];

$que = "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid1','$answ1','$point1')";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid2','$answ2','$point2')";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid3','$answ3','$point3')";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid4','$answ4','$point4')";

$run = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli,$que);
if($run)
{
 echo "<br>Information stored successfully";

}
else
{
 echo mysql_error();
}


?>
```

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and you'll see that you are missing semicolons between your calls. Additionally, your code is wide open to SQL injection (check the POST arrays before it gets stored in the db).

Comment: $mysqli(connection object) where did youdefined

Comment: You are mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment (added semicolons):

```
$que = "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid1','$answ1','$point1');";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid2','$answ2','$point2');";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid3','$answ3','$point3');";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid4','$answ4','$point4');";

$run = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli,$que);
```

See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) where it clearly reads:

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a
>   semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

In case you just need to insert these data, there is no need for multiple query, Use this for running your code as one query:

```
$que = "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid1','$answ1','$point1'), ";
$que .= "('$pid5','','$aid2','$answ2','$point2'), ";
$que .= "('$pid5','','$aid3','$answ3','$point3'), ";
$que .= "('$pid5','','$aid4','$answ4','$point4');";

$run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $que);
```

Comment: I want to upvote this for showing how to do multi-insert correctly. But then I realised you're still injecting untrusted variables into the query so I have to downvote you. Conclusion: no vote.